# Is akkusativ or Dative Object pronoun used in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun, dative, accusative, accusative-and-infinitive

The sentence is : What does my name sound like to you?

the expression "to you" what do you think it is.

If we convert into german, what would be the translation.

Will it be:

1. Was hört mein Name für dich?
2. Was hört mein Name dir?

Also what does 'für dich an' means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, *was* is the wrong word to use. Note that English does not use *what* directly either, it uses *like what*. This is a relatively recent replacement for *how*. German does not have that peculiar usage, we just use *wie*. Next, the word that your are looking for is not *hören* but [*sich anhören*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anh%C3%B6ren). Note that this is a separable verb, which probably explains the *an* that you saw somewhere and did not understand. A more direct correspondence to the English *sound* would be [*klingen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/klingen).

Now to get to your actual question, we use *für + Akkusativ* here, i.e.

> Wie klingt mein Name für Dich?

or

> Wie hört sich mein Name für Dich an?

Comment: Great!! If we translate this in english, would it be: 'How my name sounds for you?'
Won't we go for 'dir' here instead of 'für dich'.
I have now properly understood the usage of 'an' here. Thanks for that.